# Bash: different behaviour reading from file interactive/cron

Tags: arrays, bash, cron, interactive

I have a script that writes about 20 numbers line by line to a file during processing.

When the script starts again, it reads from this file with this code

```
declare -a sedum
i=0
while read -r line
do
    sedum[$i]=$line
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
done < $f_sday
```

f_sday contains the filename. When I call the script from comand line it always works fine and reads the complete content of the file.

But when the script is called in a cronjob it reads only two or three values

I know that from cron it might not be the same environment but I can't see any environmental dependency here.
I tried mapfile at first, but that read only two of the twenty values.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: How are you running the script? Does it have a `#!/bin/bash` line?

Comment: Where are you setting `$f_sday`?

Comment: The shebang is the first line. From comand line I call it with ./name.sh, from the crontab with full path.
The f_sday is set here
origdir=$(pwd)
f_sday="$origdir/7day.txt"
The values the cronjob called script reads are correct, so I assume the file is correctly found.

Comment: Do you have cron configured to send output to you via email? Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script so you can get a full trace of its execution.

Comment: I'll try that. I have code in the script:  

for i in $(seq 0 $nof)
  do
    echo $i - ${sedum[$i]} 
  done

So I see that only sedum[0] till sedum[2] are filled with the values from the file, the rest is empty. nof is 20, the number of lines in the file

Comment: Awkward, weird. I put a "cat $f_sday" in the script....the output is only 4 lines long...and the x-trace shows that these 4 values are read. But on disk the file has 20 lines..WTH?

Comment: Are you sure it's running in the right directory? `echo $f_sday`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me.

I did not control the working path (cron starts in $HOME), so the script was working on the wrong file.
Thanks for the set -x hint. That led me on the right path!